# How to load 2 database tables into the same Gridgain cache

Tags: java, database, caching, gridgain

I have two tables department (dept_id and dept) and employee(emp_id, dept_id, firstname, lastname) in a database that I want to load into the cache. I used the schema import tool and it generated the CacheConfig.java, DepartmentKey.java, Department.java, Employee.java and EmployeeKey.java files. Now Now how do I load the cache with both these tables?

Here's the snippet:

```
 private static class MySQLDemoStoreFactory<K, V> extends CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<K, V> { 
         //{@inheritDoc} 
         @Override public CacheJdbcPojoStore<K, V> create() { 


            MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource(); 
            dataSource.setURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB"); 
            dataSource.setUser("root"); 
            dataSource.setPassword("pass"); 
            setDataSource(dataSource); 
            return super.create(); 

        } 

    }
```

then in main, to load the cache:

```
try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) { 
            // Configure cache store. 
            CacheConfiguration<EmployeeKey, Employee> cfg = 
                CacheConfig.cache("EmpCache", new MySQLDemoStoreFactory<EmployeeKey, Employee>()); 

            try (IgniteCache<EmployeeKey, Employee> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg)) { 
                // Preload cache from database. 
                preload(cache);
```

This will just load it with the Employee table, right? How do I load it with the Department and the Employee table both?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question was answered on the Ignite user list here:

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/How-to-load-2-tables-in-a-cache-td4026.html